# NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: python, django

I get this error on the homepage of my website:

NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'admin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [].

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'queue', views.QueueItemViewSet)
router.register(r'label', views.EventLabelViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^$', views.api_root),
    url(r'^fingerprint/submit/$', views.FingerprintSubmit.as_view(),
        name="fingerprint-submit"),
    url(r'^fingerprint/rebuild/$', views.RebuildFingerprints.as_view(),
        name="fingerprint-rebuild"),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

And here is the offending views.py snippet:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    """
    Home page of the API
    """
    return Response({
        'admin': reverse('admin', request=request, format=format)})
```

And finally, the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://128.31.25.88:8000/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['deltasherlock_server.apps.DeltasherlockServerConfig',
 'rest_framework',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  477.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  437.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  474.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
  52.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/django-server/deltasherlock_server/views.py" in api_root
  29.         'admin': reverse('admin', request=request, format=format),

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in reverse
  50.         url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in _reverse
  63.     url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'admin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have looked at other posts and haven't found anything that helped, and I just joined this project so I don't exactly know what the original programmer was trying to do here.

Comment: Try reverse('admin'), admin has no kwargs

Comment: @RanjithSinghu didn't change anything :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`admin.site.urls` is not a view, it's an URL configuration with an URL namespace of `admin`. It's a bit different because you shouldn't use `include()`, but in every other way it's like including a different URLconf.

Since it is an include, the `name` parameter has absolutely no effect.

To reverse the main page of the admin, use:

```
return Response({
    'admin': reverse('admin:index', request=request, format=format),
})
```

A full list of admin URLs can be found [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).